# Energy conservation in Barnes-Hut algorithm

Tags: galaxy-cluster, n-body-simulations

I wrote a code that follows the Barnes-Hut algorithm for gravitational dynamics. Everything looks pretty good, except that when I plot the total energy $$E_{tot}\equiv E_k+E_u=const$$ I get this result:

[image]

and you can see that although it seems constant for most of the time, it has some increasing transient in the beginning. I couldn't find a bug in the code that could be responsible for this, is there may be other explanation that can make sense of this?

Comment: We cannot see your code, so its impossible to answer. And actual coding questions should be placed on [SO]

Comment: Constants of motion not staying constant is a common problem with numerical integration codes. It needn't come from a very obvious bug, but merely from an inappropriate choice of algorithm or implementation.  I'd suggest you search the literature, as it's very unlikely you're the first to run into this.

Comment: The Barnes-Hut has major problems with discontinuity. If a star moves from an area into another, what will happen?

Comment: This is a simulation question, not a programming question; don't migrate to Stack Overflow but consider [Computational Science SE](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/). Anyway, what happens if you shorten the timestep?

Comment: What kind of integrator did you implement?

Comment: Runge-Kutte 4 order, shorten the time step didn't change anything.

Comment: A leapfrog or Verlet integrator may conserve energy better.